# Using spring framework for smaller project?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a smaller project to organize my finance and several dates and TODOs. Know I need to create different Screens and must often connect to databases to get data. I saw that the spring framework supports some stuff for jdbc and dependency injection. The last point is very important, because I want that my Classes, which creates the screen should be loosely coupled and the code should be more clear.

Is it profitable to use Spring by small projects? I may use 3 components of the whole framework and because of that I'm not sure if it is "good" style to use a big framework like these for such a small project.
Thanks for every comment.

Comment: "supports some stuff for jdbc"? Supports pretty much everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you are going to use Spring Framework or not, that's completely your choice. But I am trying to explain you where your conception about Spring Framework is completely wrong.

You have said-

> Is it profitable to use Spring by small projects? I may use **3 components of the whole framework** and because of that i'm not sure if it is "good" sytle to use a big framework like these for such a small project.

[From Spring reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/)

> The Spring Framework is a lightweight solution and a potential one-stop-shop for building your enterprise-ready applications. However, **Spring is modular, allowing you to use only those parts that you need**, without having to bring in the rest. You can use the IoC container, with any web framework on top, but you can also use only the Hibernate integration code or the JDBC abstraction layer.

It is clear that, ***you can only use those modules of Spring, which are required for your project without having to bring in the rest.***

### Spring Modules

> The Spring Framework consists of features organized into about 20 modules. These modules are grouped into Core Container, Data Access/Integration, Web, AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming), Instrumentation, Messaging, and Test, as shown in the following diagram.

[image]

Any way, although Spring Framework provides comprehensive infrastructure support for developing applications but for the novice user, *it is **tougher to use the framework quickly** as it has complex abstraction and user has to spend more time in assessing the concept, function and it's uses in developing the application.*